# Implementing cache for server

Tags: c#, performance, cache

I've just implemented a cache for my server, and I'd like your thoughts about performance improvements and maybe some possible bug fixes:

```
public class Cache<CacheKey, CacheValue>
{
    private Dictionary<CacheKey, KeyValuePair<CacheValue, DateTime>> _map;

    /// <summary>
    /// The first element is the least recently used.
    /// </summary>
    private List<CacheKey> _lru;

    private int _maxSize;

    private ReaderWriterLock _lock;

    private int _minutes;

    public Cache(int maxNumberOfRecords, int minutes)
    {
        _maxSize = Math.Max(maxNumberOfRecords, 1);
        _lru = new List<CacheKey>(_maxSize + 1);
        _map = new Dictionary<CacheKey, KeyValuePair<CacheValue, DateTime>>();
        _lock = new ReaderWriterLock();
        _minutes = minutes;
    }

    public CacheValue find(CacheKey key)
    {
        _lock.AcquireReaderLock(-1);

        CacheValue ans;

        if (_map.ContainsKey(key) && (DateTime.Now - _map[key].Value).Minutes < _minutes)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>            //don't wait for lru to update
            {
                _lock.AcquireWriterLock(-1);
                _lru.Remove(key);
                _lru.Add(key);
                _lock.ReleaseWriterLock();
            });

            ans = _map[key].Key;
        }
        else
        {
            ans = default(CacheValue);
        }

        _lock.ReleaseReaderLock();
        return ans;
    }

    public void insert(CacheKey key, CacheValue value)
    {
        _lock.AcquireWriterLock(-1);

        if (_map.ContainsKey(key))      //if exists
        {
            _map.Remove(key);
            _map.Add(key, new KeyValuePair<CacheValue, DateTime>(value, DateTime.Now));       //update value
        }
        else
        {                               //if not
            _lru.Add(key);
            _map.Add(key, new KeyValuePair<CacheValue, DateTime>(value, DateTime.Now));       //add to cache

            if (_lru.Count > _maxSize)
            {
                _map.Remove(_lru[0]);   //and delete least recently used

                _lru.RemoveAt(0);
            }
        }

        _lock.ReleaseWriterLock();
    }
}
```

I've used `ThreadPool` because the `List` operations are expensive, but I think that this hurts the LRU integrity.  I'm also thinking to implement a queue with \$O(1)\$ `Remove` to replace the `List` class.

Comment: Don't use `DateTime.Now`.  Use `DateTime.UtcNow`.  You don't want to introduce caching bugs when daylight savings changes kick in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using .NET 4 or above drop your code, and use [MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).